# OpenCv compilation on raspberry pi stops at 16%

Tags: opencv, software-compilation

I was installing OPENCV on raspberry pi and all are done but when the compilation of opencv it stops at 16%.I used make -j4 as well as make -j1.It gives no error and it comes to build folder.

This is the code which i have used,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ source ~/.profile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ workon cv
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls
Desktop    get-pip.py    opencv-3.1.0          opencv.zip  python_games  Videos
Documents  Music         opencv_contrib-3.1.0  Pictures    Templates
Downloads  oldconffiles  opencv_contrib.zip    Public      tf
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd opencv-3.1.0/build
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $ make -j4
[ 16%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 16%] Built target libwebp
[ 16%] Built target IlmImf
[ 16%] Built target opencv_core
[ 16%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 16%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 16%] Built target opencv_surface_matching
[ 16%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 16%] Built target opencv_video
[ 16%] Built target opencv_reg
[ 16%] Built target opencv_photo
[ 16%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 16%] Built target opencv_fuzzy
[ 16%] Built target opencv_shape
[ 16%] Built target opencv_videoio
[ 16%] Built target opencv_dnn
[ 16%] Built target opencv_superres
[ 16%] Built target opencv_highgui
[ 16%] Built target example_surface_matching_ppf_normal_computation
[ 16%] Built target example_surface_matching_ppf_load_match
[ 16%] Built target example_reg_map_test
[ 16%] Built target opencv_ts
[ 16%] Built target example_fuzzy_fuzzy_inpainting
[ 16%] Built target example_fuzzy_fuzzy_filtering
[ 16%] Built target example_dnn_caffe_googlenet
[ 16%] Built target opencv_objdetect
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_superres
[ 16%] Built target opencv_plot
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_superres
[ 16%] Built target opencv_xphoto
[ 16%] Built target opencv_bgsegm
[ 16%] Built target opencv_dpm
[ 16%] Built target opencv_bioinspired
[ 16%] Built target opencv_face
[ 16%] Built target opencv_annotation
[ 16%] Built target opencv_features2d
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_flann
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_core
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_core
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_ml
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_photo
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_imgproc
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_photo
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_imgproc
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_reg
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_reg
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_video
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_video
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_dnn
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_fuzzy
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_imgcodecs
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_shape
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_imgcodecs
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_videoio
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_objdetect
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_highgui
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_videoio
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_objdetect
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_xphoto
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_xphoto
[ 16%] Built target example_xphoto_simple_color_balance
[ 16%] Built target opencv_xobjdetect
[ 16%] Built target example_xphoto_grayworld_color_balance
[ 16%] Built target example_xphoto_dct_image_denoising
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_bgsegm
[ 16%] Built target example_xphoto_inpainting
[ 16%] Built target example_bgsegm_bgfg_gmg
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_bioinspired
[ 16%] Built target example_bioinspired_OpenEXRimages_HDR_Retina_toneMapping
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_bioinspired
[ 16%] Built target example_bioinspired_basicRetina
[ 16%] Built target example_bioinspired_retinaDemo
[ 16%] Built target example_dpm_cascade_detect_sequence
[ 16%] Built target example_dpm_cascade_detect_camera
[ 16%] Built target example_face_facerec_eigenfaces
[ 16%] Built target example_face_facerec_fisherfaces
[ 16%] Built target example_face_facerec_video
[ 16%] Built target example_face_facerec_demo
[ 16%] Built target example_face_facerec_lbph
[ 16%] Built target example_face_facerec_save_load
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_features2d
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_features2d
[ 16%] Built target opencv_line_descriptor
[ 16%] Built target opencv_saliency
[ 16%] Built target opencv_text
[ 16%] Built target opencv_waldboost_detector
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_line_descriptor
[ 16%] Built target example_line_descriptor_compute_descriptors
[ 16%] Built target opencv_calib3d
[ 16%] Built target example_line_descriptor_lines_extraction
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_line_descriptor
[ 16%] Built target example_line_descriptor_knn_matching
[ 16%] Built target example_line_descriptor_lsd_lines_extraction
[ 16%] Built target example_line_descriptor_matching
[ 16%] Built target example_line_descriptor_radius_matching
[ 16%] Built target example_saliency_computeSaliency
[ 16%] Built target example_text_segmented_word_recognition
[ 16%] Built target example_text_cropped_word_recognition
[ 16%] Built target example_text_webcam_demo
[ 16%] Built target example_text_character_recognition
[ 16%] Built target example_text_textdetection
[ 16%] Built target example_text_end_to_end_recognition
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_calib3d
[ 16%] Built target opencv_ccalib
[ 16%] Built target opencv_datasets
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_calib3d
[ 16%] Built target opencv_rgbd
[ 16%] Built target opencv_stereo
[ 16%] Built target opencv_aruco
[ 16%] Built target opencv_videostab
[ 16%] Built target opencv_xfeatures2d
[ 16%] Built target opencv_ximgproc
[ 16%] Built target opencv_createsamples
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_hog
[ 16%] Built target opencv_traincascade
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_clahe
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_pyrlk_optical_flow
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_bgfg_segm
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_camshift
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_tvl1_optical_flow
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_squares
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_ufacedetect
[ 16%] Built target example_ccalib_multi_cameras_calibration
[ 16%] Built target example_ccalib_random_pattern_generator
[ 16%] Built target example_ccalib_omni_stereo_calibration
[ 16%] Built target example_ccalib_random_pattern_calibration
[ 16%] Built target example_ccalib_omni_calibration
[ 16%] Built target example_datasets_tr_svt_benchmark
[ 16%] Built target example_datasets_tr_svt
[ 16%] Built target example_datasets_tr_icdar
[ 16%] Built target example_datasets_tr_chars_benchmark
[ 16%] Built target example_datasets_track_vot
[ 16%] Built target example_datasets_slam_tumindoor
[ 16%] Built target example_datasets_slam_kitti
[ 16%] Built target example_datasets_pd_inria[ 16%] Built target opencv_ximgproc
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_ximgproc
[ 16%] Built target example_ximgproc_disparity_filtering
[ 16%] Built target example_ximgproc_niblack_thresholding
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_ximgproc[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_clahe
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_pyrlk_optical_flow
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_bgfg_segm
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_camshift
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_tvl1_optical_flow
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_squares
[ 16%] Built target example_tapi_ufacedetect
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $
```

Comment: Without any errors, etc it's a bit of a guess. Maybe the Pi ran out of memory? Do you have swap activated during the build? And if you're on Stretch you could actually try to install it from Pypi / piwheels. There are precompiled wheels available for the standard OpenCV packages (and Python 3). In a Python 3 virtual environment you can install it with `pip install`

Comment: When using make -j4 it was stucked and then i used j1.This happened after using j1.okay i'll have a try with piwheel.Let's see whether it works or not..Thanks